# Search drop down by value & text with jQuery RSS

Tags: jquery, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown in my page like this way

```
<select name="cboService" id="cboService" tabindex="10">
<option selected="selected" value="Novalue">Select Service</option>
<option value="011">UPS Standard -- £11</option>
</select>
```

I want to search the data in the drop down by value or text. If a value is found then the option will be selected and if it's not found, a new option will be added to dropdown and be selected once it's added.

Could someone offer suggestions on how to do this with jQuery.

Comment: at what event you are trying to search in dropdown ?

Comment: suppose i will search dropdown in button click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write logic like below :

Below is search input and button -

```
<input id="searchInput">
<input type="button" id="searchBtn" value="search">
```

Use below jQuery to search from dropdown -

```
$(function(){
    $('#searchBtn').click(function(){
      var valueToSearch = $('#searchInput').val();
      var found =  $('#cboService option').filter(function(){
            if(valueToSearch== $(this).val() || valueToSearch== $(this).text())
            {
                $(this).prop('selected', true);
                return true;
            }
                return false;
        });

       if(found.length==0)
       {
          $('#cboService').append('<option value="'+valueToSearch+'" selected>'+valueToSearch+'</option>'); 
       }
    });
});
```

**[Working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JkZ6Z/7/)**

Comment: thanks for answer but i like to know that filter() & prop() function will work when we work with jquery version jquery-1.4.1.js ??

Comment: .filter() will work but use .attr() instead of .prop() (.prop added in version 1.6)